# Difference between Query .list and .getResultList

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Recently, If you are using Hibernate 5.2 or higher, then the `Query::list()` method has been deprecated.

Now, what the difference in using these two methods?

If anyone knows, please explain with examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of Hibernate 3.2 says that [Query#list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) returns the query as `List<T>`.

> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

As you can read from the newer documentation of Hibernate 5.2 about the same named class and its method [Query#getResultList](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html) is the overridden implementation of the the `javax` interface's method [TypedQuery#getResultList](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getResultList()).

> Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as a typed List.

This method is a replacement of the one from the previous versions.

The idea is to implement Java EE interface (most of `javax` library) and keep the naming consistent.